# android media picker from Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writting an application with xamarin forms for iOS and Android.

I want to pick a photo from image gallery.

I have created an android specific static helper:

```
var i = new Intent();
i.SetType("*/*");
Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(i, ""));
```

But i have no way to get the selected picture bytes.
I have seen on android tutorials i should implement onActivityResult, but i am not on an activity, this is a specific static call...

Thanks

Comment: why not use the Media plugin?  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

Comment: There is no way to get the picture without implementing OnActivityResult. As Jason suggested, you should use James Montemagno's plugin :)

Comment: i want to understand how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via a Form's dependency service:

- Create your dependency interface (`IMediaPicker`)
- Create a Activity subclass (`MediaChooserActivityProxy`) that will act as your `Intent.ActionPick` proxy
- In your `Xamarin.Android` implementation of the `IMediaPicker`, use a `AutoResetEvent` to *convert* the Android `StartActivityForResult` / `OnActivityResult` callback to an await-able synchronous flow.

#### Dependency Service Interace:

```
public interface IMediaPicker
{
    Task<string> ChooseAFileAsync();
}
```

#### Android Dependency Implementation:

```
public class MediaPicker : IMediaPicker
{
    public static string filePickedPath;
    public static AutoResetEvent waitHandle;

    public async Task<string> ChooseAFileAsync()
    {
        waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        filePickedPath = "";
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(typeof(MediaChooserActivityProxy));
        await Task.Run(() => waitHandle.WaitOne());
        return filePickedPath;
    }
}
```

#### The Proxy/Pseudo Activity to capture `OnActivityResult`:

```
public class MediaChooserActivityProxy : Activity
{
    const string mimeType = "image/*";
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick);
        intent.SetType(mimeType);
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraMimeTypes, mimeType);
        }
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "StackOverflow"), 73);
    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 73)
            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                string[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.Data };
                var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(data.Data, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.MoveToFirst();
                var colummIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                MediaPicker.filePickedPath = cursor.GetString(colummIndex);
            }
        MediaPicker.waitHandle.Set();
        Finish();
    }
}
```

Note: This can be implemented on the MainActivity/FormsAppCompatActivity to avoid this additional Activity if desired...

#### Usage:

```
var filePath = await DependencyService.Get<IMediaPicker>().ChooseAFileAsync();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(filePath);
```

Comment: I get this exception at runtime: Android.Content.ActivityNotFoundException MediaChooserActivityProxy}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, but i put this in manifest: <application android:label="myapp"><activity android:name=".Droid.MediaChooserActivityProxy" android:screenOrientation="portrait" /></application>

Comment: @Bob5421 Remove that from your manifest and add an `Activity` attribute to the `MediaChooserActivityProxy` class, i.e. `[Activity(Label = "MediaChooserActivityProxy")]`

Comment: Now i have an exception access to the path propertystore.forms is denied

Comment: @Bob5421 not sure, but review these: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/43135/sharing-violation-on-path-propertystore-forms-tmp https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28709